# fast saving of a vector in a csv file with c ++ under windows 10

Tags: c++, csv

My program reads a file, processes it and saves the results in a **csv** file.
The whole of us include a loop in which many different files are processed. a separate csv file is generated for each of these files.
I was able to implement the processing very efficiently in terms of time, so that saving the respective results is the longest process in the loop.
The results are available as `vector <float>` and are currently saved as follows:

```
    std::vector<float*> out = calculation(bla);

    fstream data;
    data.open(savepfad + name + ".csv", ios::out);
    data<< sizex << endl;
    data<< sizey << endl;
    data<< dim << endl;

    for (int d = 0; d < dim; d++)
    {       
        for (int x = 0; x < sizex * sizey; x++)
        {
            data << out[d][x] << ",";
        }
        data << endl;
    }
    data.close();
```

my first thought was that i would simply outsource the storage process to a new thread (possibly with a fork) so i could continue with the main loop. But I use windows.
can I somehow write the data to the hard drive faster?
does anyone have a brilliant idea?

**EDIT:**
so i rebuilt the code according to the statements, but there is no real speed advantage. The code now looks like this:

```
    std::vector<float*> out = calculation(bla);

    string line =  std::to_string(sizex) + "\n" + std::to_string(sizey ) + "\n" + std::to_string(dim) + "\n";

    for (int d = 0; d < dim; d++)
    {       
        for (int x = 0; x < sizex * sizey; x++)
        {
            line += out[d][x];
            line += ",";
        }
        line += "\n";
    }
    fstream data;
    data.open(savepfad + name + ".csv", ios::out);
    data<<line;
    data.close();
```

I also noticed that if out [] [] = 0 hours :: to_string (out [] []) makes 0 from 0.00 to 0.000000, and a data << out [] [] only writes 0 into the file. this makes the file size from 8000KB to 36000KB.
So if I can dump quasi instant 100MB onto the hard disk in python, I have to be able to write 8000KB relatively quickly, currently it takes between 1 and 2 minutes.

example size:

```
sizex = 638
sizey = 958
dim = 8
```

The time measurement shows that it takes almost the entire time to go through the two loops. it is a vector consisting of arrays. is the access to out too slow?

Comment: Is `line += to_string(x)` really faster than `data << x`? How much data? How long does it take?

Comment: There's nothing your C++ program can do that will make your hard drive spin faster than it already does. C++ can do a lot of things but, that, unfortunately, isn't one of them.

Comment: Just a thought might not be correct, dont initialize line in every loop instead do it outside once, line += std::to_string(), the place where you are doing data << endl just append endl or "\n" to line and once outer loop is finished, in one shot put everything to data

Comment: *can I somehow write the data to the hard drive faster?* -- You need to be careful about this.  What makes your code write to *your* drive faster may make writing to a different hard-drive slower or no gain at all.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it is not the solution, i edited the original post.
@Sam Varshavchik clearly c ++ cannot make my hard drive physically faster, but there can be differences in the code flow that is more efficient.

Comment: By repeatedly appending onto a string you are forced to constantly copy the string in order to resize it. Use an `ostrstream` as I said. Also profile your program to see which bit is slow.

Answer (score 5):

`data << endl` sends a newline AND flushes the result to disk.
You could do

```
data << "\n";
```

instead to send a newline without flushing.
The end result is that you flush fewer times, which means you spend less time waiting for the OS.

If that is still not fast enough, consider buffering everything into a `ostrstream` and dumping that into `data` in one go.

Comment: I consider especially the `std::endl` as a big performance leak. After I reviewed an XML writer of our own and replaced `std::endl` by `'\n'`, we earned a lot of speed-up for saving our (not that small) XML files. And, the [Notes about `std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl#Notes) might be worth to mentioned as well.

Comment: @Scheff "encouraged by some sources" I like it how someone found nice words to express that there are just too many crap tutorials and "learning" sites out there ;)

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it is not the solution, i edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do which may help, I would try implementing them one after another and measure the performance.

1. Don't flush after every line:
   `std::endl` actually flushes the buffers and saves the file to the drive, that's probably killing the performance. So use `<< '\n';`
2. You can try to minimize memory allocation and copying, if you buffer every line (or multiple lines) before writing it out. I would try to reserve a big string (`std::string line; line.reserve(<big number enough for the full line>);`) and do `line += std::to_string(out[d][x]); line += ',';`
3. You can optimize this even further, and you can try to use `std::to_chars`.

+1. If you are on windows, you can try to use the latest MSVC, they reported 5x speedup in float to string conversion (compared to crt functions), after implementing to_chars. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4P_kbF0EbZM

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it is not the solution, i edited the original post.